# Creating/editing textfile through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text-files

How do I code the algorithm below in VB.NET?

```
Procedure logfile()
{
    if "C:\textfile.txt"=exist then
        open the textfile;
    else
        create the textfile;
    end if  
    go to the end of the textfile;
    write new line in the textfile;
    save;
    close;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\textfile.txt"
Dim i As Integer
Dim aryText(4) As String

aryText(0) = "Mary WriteLine"
aryText(1) = "Had"
aryText(2) = "Another"
aryText(3) = "Little"
aryText(4) = "One"

Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)

For i = 0 To 4
    objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))
Next

objWriter.Close()
MsgBox("Text Appended to the File")
```

If you set the second parameter to `True` in the `System.IO.StreamWriter`'s constructor it will append to a file if it already exists, or create a new one if it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved in a single line too:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filePath, "Hello World" & vbCrLf)
```

It will create the file if missing, append the text and close it again.

See MSDN, [File.AppendAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use a component that does this type of logging out of the box.  The [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139916.aspx) from [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx) for example.  That way, you get flexibility, scalability and don't have contention with your log file.

To answer your question specifically (sorry, I don't know VB, but the translation should be simple enough) ...

```
void Main()
{
    using( var fs = File.Open( @"c:\textfile.txt", FileMode.Append ) )
    {
        using( var sw = new StreamWriter( fs ) )
        {
          sw.WriteLine( "New Line" );
          sw.Close();
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 For editing :
 Try
     Dim thefile As String = "C:\con_ip.txt" 'Put your path
     Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\con_ip.txt")
     lines(Put which line to edit) = "Put the Value to edit "
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(thefile, lines)
 Catch ex As Exception

 End Try
```