# How to open Notepad from a Windows Forms application and place some text in it?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm using VB.NET and Visual Studio 2008.

My question is: How do I open Notepad from a Windows Forms application, and then place some text string in the Notepad window?

Comment: Notepad is simply a `TextBox` control with a menu bar. It would be much easier and more productive to add a `TextBox` control to your form (or a second form), and display the text there. Opening another process, finding its window handle, sending it messages, and all of the other things that would be required by a *true* solution to your problem are really not the best way of going about this, and certainly not simple. If you're just starting out in WinForms development, you *definitely* don't need to stop and learn all about the Windows API.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm trying to create a letter template, so that the new NOTEPAD will contain the saved letter head, etc for user to add his own letter content, then save, print it out, etc

Comment: Ah, so then the answers below have you covered. Create a text file, and then use the Windows Shell to open Notepad displaying that text file. `Process.Start` is your starting point once you've created the text document on disk.

Comment: @Cody Gray: OK, I knew what you mean, thanks for the clue.

Comment: You can use a Notepad clone that gives you a lot more control with source code so you can embed right into your application. You can find it here: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2012/04/notepad-clone-in-net-winforms.html (Similar to what @CodyGray is describing, except it behaves exactly like notepad)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use `Process.Start` with the property `ShellExecute` set to `true`;
2. Use the clipboard: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/40011-how-do-i-put-text-in-another-program/

### Update

`Process.Start` returns a `Process` object which has a `MainWindowHandle` property. Use that handle when sending text instead of the FindWindow in the above mentioned link.

### Update 2

Some code

```
Const WM_SETTEXT As Integer = &HC
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> lParam As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Shared Sub Main()
    'ProcessStartInfo is used to instruct the Process class
    ' on how to start a new process. The UseShellExecute tells
    ' the process class that it (amongst other) should search for the application
    ' using the PATH environment variable.
    Dim pis As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
    pis.UseShellExecute = True

    ' The process class is used to start the process
    ' it returns an object which can be used to control the started process
    Dim notepad As Process = Process.Start(pis)

    ' SendMessage is used to send the clipboard message to notepad's
    ' main window.
    Dim textToAdd As String = "Text to add"
    SendMessage(notepad.MainWindowHandle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, textToAdd)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes to the first part, no to the second part. `FindWindow` is explicitly what you should *not* use here. Far too fragile, and unnecessarily complicated for someone new to WinForms programming. All they'll know how to do is copy and paste that code; they'll be helpless when it doesn't work. And that's hardly unexpected. (This is also why I edited the part about him being a newbie to WinForms back into the question; I think it should be answered at least with that in mind.)

Comment: @Code Gray: I didn't add the link for the `FindWindow` part, but for the SendMessage part. But you're right. I should have been more clear about that. Hence the update of my answer.

Comment: added some code. Used a C# to vb.net converter (hope that the code is correct)

Comment: @jgauffin: ha ha, your update #2 makes me puzzled, particularly the 'Dim pis = New ProcessStartInfo' line. Anyway thanks for efforts.

Comment: Much better answer. I fixed the VB.NET code to be more idiomatic.

Comment: @Cody Gray: thanks for your help. jgauffin's code maybe too advanced for me.

Comment: @david: Well, I'm quite impressed that you're trying to *understand* the code you're using, rather than just copying and pasting it directly from someone's answer. That means a lot right there.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest approach is to write a text-file, then open that, rather than the other way round.

You can use [System.File.IO.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx), and the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

A quick code-sample would be along these lines:

```
File.WriteAllText (
    @"C:\temp\myFile.txt", 
    "This is my letter header\nIt has a new-line in it")
Process.Start("notepad.exe", @"C:\temp\myFile.txt");
```

Comment: That's what I'd suggest too. Remember, you can always use `Path.GetTempFileName()` to get a temporary filename. No matter it doesn't return a `.txt` file (although you can force it): *Notepad* will still open it.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to make a text file, and pass it to Notepad as a command line argument, or, if Notepad is the default application for ".txt", you can shell straight to the filename.

[Creating/editing textfile through VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332260/creating-editing-textfile-through-vb-net)

[Launch and watch a process from VB.NET 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249852/launch-and-watch-process-from-vb-net-2010)

You can use the arguments collection `ProcessStartInfo` to pass the filename if required.