# Opening an in memory string with notepad

Tags: c#, winforms, process, notepad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open Notepad from a Windows Forms application and place some text in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702669/how-to-open-notepad-from-a-windows-forms-application-and-place-some-text-in-it)

I want to open a string sequence (made using `StringBuilder`) which is still in memory with default text editor of the PC. I know that if I save the file first in a location I can use the code below:

`Process.Start(@"notepad.exe", pathToFile);`

Or more general:
`Process.Start(pathToFile);`

But I wonder if there is a way to do this without saving the file on disk?